# WPF: Databinding ComboBox to int value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class like this:

```
public class Service
{
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind it to a ComboBox so the combo shows "Active"/"Inactive" and the State becomes 1 or 0?

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=State}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Active" Tag="1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Inactive" Tag="0" />
</ComboBox>
```

I'm binding the object to the form using DataContext `form.DataContext = new Service();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you would use a [value converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html), but in this scenario you can easily use a dictionary.

Something like this should work:

```
public class Service
{
   public Dictionary<int,string> StateDictonary {get;set;}

    public Service()
    {
      StateDictonary = new Dictionary<int,string>();
      StateDictonary[1] = "Active";
      StateDictonary[0] = "Inactive";
    }
}
```

Then in the xaml you would do something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StateDictonary }"   DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

I'm at home now, so I can't test this. so let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: It did not work with a Dictionary, but I'll try with a List<Tuple<int, string>> when I get home.

Comment: Yeah... I forgot to add a public modifier to the property. binding won't work with private members (:

I tested it now and it works perfect. (updated my answer)

Comment: How can I make Active the default selected item with this code?

Comment: @Ozkan add a int property to the viewModel and bind the SelectedValue property of the ComboBox to that int property. if the int property is set to 1 before the view loads, it will be defaulted to Active.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Tag attribute just holds whatever data you give it, it has no contribution to binding of SelectedItem. If ComboBoxItems have no datacontext, you might be able to do this, give it a try:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=State}" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Active" Tag="1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Inactive" Tag="0" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Not sure that's going to work, he would need to set up a data context with the "Tag" property (some kind of relative source binding to the UI element).

Comment: @LordTakkera - It will work because right now child items are ComboBoxItems which do have `Tag` property.

Comment: First +1 for you PauliusP.. Welcome to SO.. :) But still OP need to set DataContext and this will work.

Comment: But will it know the Tag is an int? I'll set a DataContext directly to see if that works.

Comment: It's not a question of knowing if it's int or not, basically you just have to have compatible type in there, which can be cast to the type you require. So string "235" would be compatible, but I believe string "235.54" won't, same goes for any other characters in Tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this:

1. A bit of a hack, but you could just reverse the order of your items and bind to SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem. This, of course, doesn't work if you need different numbers or need that specific order.
2. Instead of statically declaring the two options, you could have a list of "State" objects with a string and int property in your view model. You would then set the ItemsSource of the combo box to this collection, and your "State" property in the view model changes to this new type. You would set the "DisplayMemberPath" property of the combo box to the string property. Then you can just get the int out of the SelectedItem. This is probably the most easily extensible solution. You could even use an enum instead of an int (more readable).
3. Make the "State" property an object (or even a String) and in it's setter, check against your two labels. Depending on which label it is, set the "real" int property to the correct value.

Personally, I would go the second route if you think you might ever have another state, and use the enum instead of a straight int. I can provide an example if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an object as the `ItemsSource` for your `ComboBox`. Since you defined the items in the `ComboBox`, the underlying data type is a `ComboBoxItem` for its `ItemsSource` and doing a binding against the `SelectedItem` it will map it to the underlying datatype. Since you are trying to data bind a value that is `int` which is not the data type for the combobox's `ItemsSource` that won't work.

To do this, I would do something like this

```
public class Service
{
    private State _selectedState;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<State> _states = new ObservableCollection<State>() { new State() { Value = "Active", IsSelected = true} ,new State() {Value = "Inactive" }};

    public State SelectedSelectedState
    {
        get { return _selectedState; }
        set
        {
            _selectedState = value;
            BitState = _selectedState.Value == "Active" ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    public int BitState { get; set; }

    public class State
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<State> States
    {
        get { return _states; }
    }
}
```

And on MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 comboBox.DataContext = new Service();
}
```

If you don't want it this control then you can do something like this,

```
    public enum State
    {
        Inactive,
        Active,
    }

    public class Service
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<State> _states = new ObservableCollection<State>() { State.Inactive, State.Active };
        private int _selectedValue;

        public int SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _selectedValue; }
            set { _selectedValue = value; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<State> States
        {
            get { return _states; }
        }
    }
```

And your XAML

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="blah" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding States}"/>
```

Comment: This looks so complex for something so simple, I was trying to avoid that :) I'll choose this if I find no simpler way.

Comment: Updated my answer if you want simple case, just use `SelectedIndex`